# How to Open Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I have created(installed `composer create-project laravel/laravel basicwebsite`) project named basicwebsite.
After that i run `php artisan serve` then it showed some URL then i got LARAVEL page in browser,fine.
(Accidentally, my system is shut down.)
To reopen the project ,in cmd prompt i just did as

`php artisan serve`
and the error occur is

[image]

I almost searched for solution in all websites(including stack) .All started with create project but not what to do after close and opened the project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm new to this Laravel and this is my 1st project

Comment: try to run `composer dump-autoload` & `composer install` again

Comment: it worked i got `Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>` in cmd. But when i copy and paste this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` in browser the  output appears as **Whoops, looks like something went wrong.** instead of **LARAVEL**  @Hussein

Comment: does it show you specific error ?

Comment: no error:The command prompt as

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/20874

Comment: php artisan config:clear use this command and run again

Answer (score -1):

Use `php artisan config:clear` command to clear cache. You should see

> Configuration cache cleared

Use `php artisan serve` command to start the server.

Comment: The error shown will cause `php artisan config:clear` to fail, too.